# NoClassDefFoundError for grizzly HTTP server

Tags: java, gradle, jersey

I am trying to execute a Grizzly HTTP Server inside a container.

Why i have this error, while running jar:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServer
```

All was allright in maven with pom, but i met this error in gradle.
This is my **build.gradle**:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:0.13.0",
    }
}

group 'com.mycompany'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'

docker {
    name "${project.group}/${jar.baseName}"
    files 'build/libs'
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${jar.archiveName}"])
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.mycompany.json_validator.Main'
    }


    baseName = 'JSON_validator-boot-docker'
    version =  '0.2.0'
    archiveName = 'JSON_validator-boot-docker-0.2.0.jar'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

        dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-moxy', version: '2.26'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-multipart', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-grizzly2-http', version: '2.17'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey', name: 'jersey-bom', version: '2.17', ext: 'pom'
}
```

All in all, i want to build jar for docker.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServer

`NoClassDefFoundError` indicates  definition of the class could be found at the runtime, this could be missing jar/libraries. Make sure, you have included `grizzly-http-server-x.x.x.jar` and related jars in classpath.